# How to divide all prices by lets say 3 for a Customer Group in Magento

Tags: magento

I am currently showing retail prices in Magento.

I would like to show different prices for wholesale customer group and I would like to divide all prices by 3 to show for logged in users that are in the wholesale customer group.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add price customer group wise for each products from magento backend

Go to product >> price tab

you will see Group Price option select your group in your case add price for wholesale group then add your other price for general users.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have 2000 products isnt there a simpler way?

Comment: no I don't think so there is no global option for it. You may have to look for an extension or do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I did it.

I found this extension Price factor http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/price-factor.html which multiplies the price with any number you specify.

Then from the extension file /app/code/community/Psquared/PriceFactor/Model/Observer.php

I added some code

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    //$customer_group_id=$customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customer_group_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 
if ($customer_group_id!=2)
{

    // code of the default if statements

}
```